# Interesting conundrum on the selecting elements from 1 to 1000 that can't form triangles

Tags: triangles, triangle-inequality

What is the largest number of distinct elements  from set $\{1,2,3,4, \cdots, 1000\}$ that you can choose from such that no three of them are the side lengths of a triangle?

This was once in a high school junior maths competition so I would prefer a solution that does not involve complicated set notation..etc.

What I know is for a set of three elements to NOT be a triangle, then

$$
\begin{align}
a+b \le c \\
a+c \le b \\
b+c \le a \\
\end{align}
$$

By the way, does anybody know what sort of question this is specifically categorised as?

Comment: Its called Triangle Inequality. Sum of lengths of two sides of a triangle must be **greater than** the third side.

Comment: Maybe try the Fibonaccis, $1,2,3,5,8,13,\dots$.

Comment: @Gyer why would the fibonaccis be involved tho?

Comment: I don't know who "Gyer" is, but I think the answer posted by user D S shows how the Fibonaccis enter the discussion.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I meant "Gerry" sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $S$ be the required set.
Any three elements from $S$ can form the triple $(a,b,c)$, where we assume without loss of generality, $a<b<c$ (since each of them is distinct).

Let us instead consider when a triangle can be drawn:
$$a+b - k=c$$
where $k$ is any positive integer (since the given set contains integers). Now, if $k$ is a non-positive integer (as it implies $c\ge a+b$), then a triangle cannot be drawn. So, if one wants to maximise $n(S)$, we need to make $k$ as small as possible, so that $c-b$ is as least as possible (or to minimise the difference between two consecutive elements when they are arranged in increasing order), meaning $S$ contains maximum elements. So, let $k = 0$.

We get:
$$a+b = c$$ Suppose we have $n$ elements of $S$ with us. Then, one can find the two largest largest elements $m$ and $n$ of this set and the $n+1$ the element of $S$ will be $m+n$, provided $m+n\le 1000$.

Now, one can start with 1 and 2 (Starting with the smallest possible numbers would maximise $n(S)$. So, the next element is 3, then 5. One can observe that this is a Fibonacci Series (except that it starts from the second term). The Fibonacci series is of the form : $$F_0 = 1$$$$F_1 = 1$$$$F_n = F_{n-1}+F_{n-2}$$ where $n\ge2$. But our series starts from $F_1$.

Now, the Fibonacci series can be computed easily by computers or even manually. After calculating, you should get:
$$S = {1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34,55,89,144,233,377,610,987}$$
$$n(S) = 15$$

Thus, one can choose no more than **15** distinct terms from ${1,2,3,4,5...1000}$, such that no three elements form a triangle.

Comment: A few notes:    1. $n(S)$ just represents the number of elements in $S$.   2. $F_n$ represents the $n$th Fibonacci number.

Comment: when you said "Now, if  is a non-positive integer, then a triangle cannot be drawn", did you mean "if k is a positive integer"?

Comment: sorry, I did not quite understand the reasoning behind making k closer to zero and also the third paragraph.

Comment: @Lawrence suppose I took $k=1$, then after first starting with 1 and 2, one would get $1+2+1 = 4$, then $2+4+1 = 7$, then $7+4+1 = 12$, then $12 + 7 + 1 = 20$. Notice how fast values are growing as compared to the $k = 0$ case. If you take $k = 2$, then the values will grow even faster: $1,2,5,9,16,$ **27** , while the first few terms of the original series were just $1,2,3,5,8,$ **13** . Do you get it now? If the terms grow faster, they will reach 1000 sooner, so you'll have _fewer_ terms in $S$.

Comment: @Lawrence non-positive integer means negative integers as well as _zero_. Let us assume  $k\ge0$, then whatever be the values of $a$ and $b$, $c$ will always be greater than or equal to $a+b$, which cannot make a triangle.